# Can I select and open multiple links in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I used to be able to select a region of a page (click and drag the mouse), right click, and open all selected links in new tabs. I have a workflow for which this is very handy. However, the functionality seems to have disappeared from Firefox. Is there any way to get it back?

This isn't a bookmark group. It might be different links each time. I just want to select multiple links on one page and open all of them in tabs. I know that I can middle click on the lot of them, but there are a few hundred.

Comment: [Workaround found](https://askubuntu.com/a/618003/652).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an Add-On called [Snap Links Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/snaplinksplus/). I think it does exactly what you want.